# Authenticating new users through mail?

Tags: php, mysql, email

so I have a table of users in my database in phpmyadmin for a website. This users table has an auto-incremented id, mail, firstname, lastname, hash(for password) and authentication_state. I want to be able to send a mail to new users that includes a link and that link makes authentication_state go from 0(the default value) to 1 wherein he is authenticated. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a verification column in your DB. Email the user a link with that verification string and their user id. On your page have it update the authenticated column. Also `phpmyadmin` is not a DB, you have a `mysql` database. You just view the data in `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Well, you need to provide some code. It will be hard to give you answer without code.Like chris mentioned you need to create a mailer in html and also need to add authentication code. After that linked get clicked you need to change value in database 0 to 1 or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

A better design would be to create a temporary users table lets call it `temp_users`. Whenever a user registers in your website the data will go to this table instead of your actual `users` table. Once the user clicks the link sent to the email address you can move the data from the temp_users table to users table. You can run a scheduler once every 24 hours or so and remove the accounts that were registered 48 hours ago but have not been verified yet. I personally feel this is a better implementation.

**Now coming to your actual question:**

Add one more column to the users table. Lets call it as `hash_code`. Whenever a new user registered compute a random series of digits or letter. MD5 encryption on timestamp is one example you can use. Along with the actual user data insert the computed hash to the table. Then send an email to the user's email, something like

```
 www.example.com/verify.php?hashcode=<The computed hash code here>&email=<email registered>
```

When the user clicks on the link he lands in the verify.php page.

In `verify.php` using $_GET to get the hashcode value and email value from the URL. Now fire an sql on your database for example,

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email=<VALUE FROM $_GET['email']> AND hash_code=<Value from $_GET['hashcode'];
```

If the SQL returns 1 then you can fire an update on the table to turn verified flag to true. If you are using a temporary table like I talked about in the beginning, You will do a select on the temporary table and insert those values to the permanent one.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am currently trying out what you said and it seems to be making progress.

Answer (score 0):

In the mail you send just include the user id in the link which they will use to go back to your site for authentication. Or you can create some `random string` instead of using the user id for security and send this string to them in the link. You can create a separate table for these authentication strings and once the user authenticates their account, delete it as you won't need it anymore

Then when they use that link to reach your authentication page, update their `authentication_state` to `1` and delete the entry of the authentication string from your database in order to keep the database well-maintained and leave only those entries that you will need time and time again.

But provide some code inorder for me to help you further.

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution.